# convert string dd-mm-yyyy to date yyyy-mm-dd in bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have 600 **string** fields in a table with format eg.,18.05.2015 and i want to convert into **date** 2015-05-18 in bigquery. I have tried using timestamp() and date() function but it is returning null values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Standard SQL

```
SELECT PARSE_DATE('%d.%m.%Y', '18.05.2015')
```

the query against table will look like

```
SELECT PARSE_DATE('%d.%m.%Y', YourDateColumn)
FROM `YourDataset.YourTable`
```

> Added to address 'broken' values

```
WITH YourTable AS (
  SELECT '18.05.2015' AS dt UNION ALL
  SELECT '#' AS dt 
)
SELECT 
  CASE WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(dt, r'\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}') 
    THEN CAST(PARSE_DATE('%d.%m.%Y', dt) AS STRING)
    ELSE dt 
  END AS new_dt
FROM YourTable
```

what this does is - process only values that match 18.05.2015 format and leaves any other untouched

> I have multiple date columns with 600 records

*Making `FINAL` attempt to interpret your comments - but honestly, still feel like it is not what you have and you are not giving clear picture, so it is best i could make for you!*

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION FIX(x STRING)
RETURNS STRING AS (
  CASE WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(x, r'\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}') 
  THEN CAST(PARSE_DATE('%d.%m.%Y', x) AS STRING) ELSE x END);

WITH YourTable AS (
  SELECT '18.05.2015' AS dt_001, '19.05.2015' AS dt_002, '21.05.2015' AS dt_003 UNION ALL
  SELECT '#' AS dt_001, '20.05.2015' AS dt_002, 'abc' AS dt_003
)
SELECT 
  FIX(dt_001) AS new_dt_001,
  FIX(dt_002) AS new_dt_002,
  FIX(dt_003) AS new_dt_003
FROM YourTable
```

Comment: how can i do apply this query on remaining fields with same format/?

Comment: clarify your question please

Comment: i am getting error as  "Failed to parse input string "#"" as there are some # symbols in some fields.I wrote the query like SELECT PARSE_DATE('%d.%m.%Y', DATE) FROM DEV(DATE is column name i gave)

Comment: it means that in some row you have junk data - not in the format you expect. do you know what you want to do with such rows? leave as is or something else?

Comment: added to answer [non]processing 'bad' values

Comment: i want to leave as is..i want to convert remaining fields

Comment: i feel like i answered your original question! if you have next question  - please feel free to post new one with respective details (in this case please vote/accept the answer as you see fit). OR if you think my answer is not really answering your original question - provide more details explaining what exactly is missing in the answer!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122953/discussion-between-nikhil-and-mikhail-berlyant).

Comment: Clarification from quick chat - just to make sure it is clear  - there are 600 rows in the table - NOT 600 fields!

Comment: if you will ask new question  - i really recommend you to provide specifics and most importantly examples of your data - input table / desired output / etc. Please make sure your question shows a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You can also read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

you can update your all the string fields from dd.mm.yyy to yyyy-mm-dd format using following query.

```
   update TABLE_NAME
      set FIELD_NAME = concat(SUBSTRING(FIELD_NAME,-4),'-',SUBSTRING(FIELD_NAME,-7,2),'-',SUBSTRING(FIELD_NAME,1,2))
```